# how to trim all the [x] enclosed bracket footnotes from a long string of Wikipedia text?

Tags: applescript, trim

I want to keep the paragraph structure but just delete all the enclosing brackets from text that is in the clipboard.

For instance - this text:

> The three stripes are Adidas' identity mark, having been used on the company's clothing and shoe designs as a marketing aid. The branding, which Adidas bought in 1952 from Finnish sports company Karhu Sports for the equivalent of 1,600 euros and two bottles of whiskey,[7][8] became so successful that Dassler described Adidas as "The three stripes company".[7][9]

I want it to be like this (no matter how long the text string):

> The three stripes are Adidas' identity mark, having been used on the company's clothing and shoe designs as a marketing aid. The branding, which Adidas bought in 1952 from Finnish sports company Karhu Sports for the equivalent of 1,600 euros and two bottles of whiskey, became so successful that Dassler described Adidas as "The three stripes company".

I've tried this but it deletes most of the string:

```
set theName to (the clipboard)
set y to characters 1 thru ¬
    ((offset of "[" in theName) - 2) ¬
        of theName as string
```

I've tried also:

```
do shell script "sed -E -e 's|\\[.*||' -e 's|,||g' -e 's|^[ ]+||' -e 's|[ ]+$||'<<<" & theName's quoted form
```

Comment: In documentation of regular expressions, look for the words “lazy” and “greedy.”  I’m not going to try to explain it because I’m not an expert either.

Answer (score 4):

Using this *regex* `\\[[^[a-zA-Z]+]` with `sed` and its `-E` *option* in a `do shell script` *command* works for me.

Note there is an extra *backslash* in the *regex* necessary to escape the other one when used in a `do shell script` *command*.  In **Terminal** it would be: `\[[^[a-zA-Z]+]`

https://regex101.com is a good resource for testing *regular expressions*.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set foo to "The three stripes are Adidas' identity mark, having been used on the company's clothing and shoe designs as a marketing aid. The branding, which Adidas bought in 1952 from Finnish sports company Karhu Sports for the equivalent of 1,600 euros and two bottles of whiskey,[7][8] became so successful that Dassler described Adidas as \"The three stripes company\".[7][9]"

set bar to do shell script "sed -E 's|\\[[^[a-zA-Z]+]||g' <<< " & foo's quoted form
```

**Result**

> "The three stripes are Adidas' identity mark, having been used on the company's clothing and shoe designs as a marketing aid. The branding, which Adidas bought in 1952 from Finnish sports company Karhu Sports for the equivalent of 1,600 euros and two bottles of whiskey, became so successful that Dassler described Adidas as "The three stripes company"."

**Notes:**

The *regex* used targets a set of *square braces* with *digits* between them. So any combination of e.g. `[1]` to any number of *digits* between the *square braces* will be removed.

---

[image]

Comment: @Alex, I appreciate the thanks, however, please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and if you feel it's appropriate to mark my answer as the accepted answer that would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @Mockman, It will not remove e.g. `[his]` now. The other one worked in https://regex101.com but not with `sed` or `gsed`.

Comment: Works well. I must confess however that I don't understand why it correctly removes the closing `]` of each reference, but not, for example a trailing digit, e.g. `[23]4`.

Comment: @Mockman, RE: "but not, for example a trailing digit, e.g. [23]4" -- The OP asked for `[x]` giving e.g. `[7][8]`, so in e.g. `[23]4` the only thing that should be removed is `[23]` leaving the `4` as `4` is not within the _square braces_. In other words, the first match is an _opening square brace_ `[` which normally needs to be escaped with a single _backslash_ but when using in a `do shell script` _command_ two are needed. The next match is anything following `[` that is not `[` or `a-zA-Z`, e.g. `[^[a-zA-Z]+` and when it matches a _closing square brace_ `]` it stops matching. Cont'd...

Comment: @Mockman, With `g` in the _editing command_ of `sed` it make the substitution for all non-overlapping matches, so each occurrence of e.g. `[1]` is treated separately, but gets removed. I know _regular expressions_ can be a pain to deal with, which is why I use https://regex101.com  to test my _regular expressions_. Although as in the case of `[his]` the _regex_ `\[[^[\D]+]` worked there but not with `sed` or `gsed` and why I switched it to `\\[[^[a-zA-Z]+]`. I'd prefer the former but will settle for the later in this particular use case. Cont'd...

Comment: @Mockman, The _regex_ `\[[^[\D]+]` would work with `perl` but it's not my go to if I can do it with `sed`. You of course probably know why some _characters_ need to be escaped, to treat them a _literals_ when they otherwise have _special meaning_.  The _closing square brace_ in this particular use case is not escaped, although it could be, because its at the end of the _regex_ and the other _square braces_ within the _regex_ are _balanced_ by `^` in front of the third _square brace_, thus not needing the last _square brace_ to be escaped and is treated as a _literal_.

Comment: @user3439894 I wasn't thinking when I suggested the perl regex — I often use BBEdit and its regex is based on PCRE. Had I been, I would have instead gone with the posix class `[:digit:]`.  Also, I was unaware of the balancing effect, and my discussion of `[23]4` was unrelated to the question and simply my attempt to better understand the regex. Thanks for taking the time to clarify this.